# BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_* macros are not working like register_type()

Tags: boost, boost-serialization

I am getting an unregistered_class exception when I serialize out a derived object to a file and serialize in from that file to a base class pointer when I use the boost export macros. When I replace the macros with the archive register_type() methods, it works. I need to use the macros because the application size and complexity makes the register_type() methods impractical.

I am using RHEL 7.4, boost 1.53, and C++11. The classes are in shared libraries. Here is sample code to demonstrate the problem. As is, it throws the exception. If I comment out the macros and uncomment the functions, it works.
testera.h

```
#ifndef testera_h
#define testera_h

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

class A
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template< class Arch >
    void
    serialize( Arch &ar, const unsigned int ver );

public:
    A(); 

    virtual ~A() {}

    void setStr( const std::string &s );
    std::string getStr();

protected:
    std::string myStr;
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(A)

#endif
```

testera.C

```
#include "testera.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(A)


template
void
A::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive>(  boost:archive::polymorphic_oarchive &ar, const unsigned int ver );

template
void
A::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive>( boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive &ar, const unsigned int ver );

A::A() : myStr( "a" ) 
{
}

void
A::setStr( const std::string &s )
{
    myStr = s;
}

std::string
A::getStr()
{
    return myStr;
}


template<class Arch>
void
A::serialize( Arch &ar, const unsigned int ver )
{
    ar & myStr;
}
```

testerb.h

```
#ifndef testerb_h
#define testerb_h

#include "testera.h"

class B : public A
{
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template< class Arch >
    void
    serialize( Arch &ar, const unsigned int ver );

public:
    B();

    virtual ~B() {}

    void set( const int i );
    int get();

protected:
    int myI;
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(B)
#endif
```

testerb.C

```
#include "testerb.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(B)

template
void 
B::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive>( boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive &ar, const unsigned int ver );

template
void
B::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive>( boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive &ar, const unsigned int ver );
B::B(): myI( 1 )
{ 
    myStr = "b"; 
}

void 
B::set( const int i ) 
{
    myI = i;
}

int 
B::get() 
{
    return myI;
}

template< class Arch >
void
B::serialize( Arch &ar, const unsigned int ver )
{
    // boost::serialization::void_cast_register< B, A >( static_cast< B *>( NULL ), static_cast< A * >( NULL ) );
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<A>( *this );

    ar & myI;
}
```

tester_mn.C

```
#include "testerb.h"
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int ret = 0;
    B obj;
    obj.set( 2 );

    A *ptr = NULL;

    if( argc > 1 )
    {
        try
        {
            std::string fl = argv[ 1 ];
            {
                std::ofstream ofl( fl.c_str() );

                /*
                oar->register_type(static_cast<A *>(NULL));
                oar->register_type(static_cast<B *>(NULL));
                */
                try
                {
                    boost::archive::polymorphic_text_oarchive toar( ofl );
                    toar & obj;
                }
                catch( std::exception &e )
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error: archive from B to file " << fl << " - " << e.what() << std::endl;
                    ret = 1;
                }
            }

            if( ! ret )
            {
                ptr = NULL;

                {
                    std::ifstream ifl( fl.c_str() );
                    /*
                    iar->register_type(static_cast<A *>(NULL));
                    iar->register_type(static_cast<B *>(NULL));
                    */

                    try
                    {
                        boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive tiar( ifl );

                        tiar & ptr;
                    }
                    catch( std::exception &e )
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Error: archive from file " << fl << " to B * - " << e.what() << std::endl;
                        ret = 1;
                    }
                    catch( ... )
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Error: Caught excpeption" << std::endl;
                        ret = 1;
                    }
                }


                if( ! ret )
                {
                    std::cout << static_cast<B*>(ptr)->get() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            std::cerr << "Caught exception" << std::endl;
            ret = 1;
        }

    }


    return ret;
}
```

Makefile_lib

```
CXXFLAGS = -c -ggdb3  -fPIC -funswitch-loops -fgcse-after-reload -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS = -std=c++11 -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

OBJLOC = obj

OBJS = $(OBJLOC)/testera.o \
    $(OBJLOC)/testerb.o

LIBRARY_NAME = libtester.so

libs:$(LIBRARY_NAME)

$(LIBRARY_NAME): $(OBJS)
    ${CXX} -shared -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJLOC)/%.o: ./%.C
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ./$*.C -o $(OBJLOC)/$*.o
```

Makefile_mn

```
CXXFLAGS = -ggdb3  -funswitch-loops -fgcse-after-reload -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS = -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -L. -ltester


tester_mn: tester_mn.o
    ${CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) tester_mn.C  -o $@
```

Comment: Can you provide a shorter, minimal working example?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with one. I removed a few unused bits and corrected a line that wasn't hit due to the exception. This was in main(). Unfortunately this is supposed to represent a shared library and an executable so this is about as simple as I can make it. If I can get a simpler one in one file and reproduce the problem I'll post it.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: [Exporting Class Serialization](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export)

> **BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT** in the same source module that includes any of the archive class headers will instantiate code required to serialize polymorphic pointers of the indicated type to the all those archive classes. **If no archive class headers are included, then no code will be instantiated.**

In this case the tricky detail is that you did include /some/ archive headers, but /not/ the concrete type that's actually doing the serialization.

Another tricky detail might be related to the question whether it still works when you have split the _KEY/_IMPLEMENT parts and you have the archive headers included before the _IMPLEMENT parts only. I suppose you could easily test this.

### Other Issues

The serialization/deserialization is not in balance. If you deserialize a `A*`, you **MUST** also serialize one of that type.

Also, you can simplify and combine the makefile, and probably don't need quite as many serialization include in your headers.

## Here The Full Code

As working locally. Just `make && ./tester_mn`:

1. testera.h

   ```
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

   class A {
     private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;

       template <class Arch> void serialize(Arch &ar, const unsigned int ver);

     public:
       A();

       virtual ~A() {}

       void setStr(const std::string &s);
       std::string getStr();

     protected:
       std::string myStr;
   };

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(A)
   ```
2. testerb.h

   ```
   #pragma once
   #include "testera.h"

   class B : public A {
     private:
       friend class boost::serialization::access;
       template <class Arch> void serialize(Arch &, unsigned);

     public:
       B();

       virtual ~B() {}
       void set(int i);
       int get();

     protected:
       int myI;
   };

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(B)
   ```
3. testera.cpp

   ```
   #include "testera.h"
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(A)

   template void A::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive>(boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive &, unsigned);
   template void A::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive>(boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive &, unsigned);

   A::A() : myStr("a")                  {               } 
   void A::setStr(const std::string &s) { myStr = s;    } 
   std::string A::getStr()              { return myStr; } 

   template <class Arch> void A::serialize(Arch &ar, unsigned) { ar &myStr; }
   ```
4. testerb.cpp

   ```
   #include "testerb.h"
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_oarchive.hpp>

   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(B)

   template void B::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive>(boost::archive::polymorphic_oarchive &, unsigned);
   template void B::serialize<boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive>(boost::archive::polymorphic_iarchive &, unsigned);

   B::B() : myI(1)          { myStr = "b"; } 
   void B::set(const int i) { myI = i;     } 
   int B::get()             { return myI;  } 

   template <class Arch> void B::serialize(Arch &ar, unsigned) {
       ar &boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
       ar &myI;
   }
   ```
5. test.cpp

   ```
   #include "testerb.h"
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_iarchive.hpp>
   #include <boost/archive/polymorphic_text_oarchive.hpp>
   #include <fstream>

   int main() try {

       std::string const fl = "test.data";
       {
           std::ofstream ofl(fl.c_str());

           boost::archive::polymorphic_text_oarchive toar(ofl);
           B obj;
           obj.set(42);

           {
               A *ptr = &obj;
               toar &ptr;
           }
       }

       {
           A *ptr = nullptr;
           std::ifstream ifl(fl.c_str());

           boost::archive::polymorphic_text_iarchive tiar(ifl);

           tiar &ptr;

           if (B *b = dynamic_cast<B *>(ptr)) {
               std::cout << b->get() << std::endl;
           }
       }
   } catch (std::exception &e) {
       std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
       return 1;
   } catch (...) {
       std::cerr << "Error: Caught excpeption" << std::endl;
       return 1;
   }
   ```
6. Makefile

   ```
   all: libs tester_mn

   CXXFLAGS += -I ~/custom/boost
   LDFLAGS  += -L ~/custom/boost/stage/lib
   CXXFLAGS += -ggdb3  -fPIC -funswitch-loops -fgcse-after-reload -std=c++11 
   LDFLAGS  += -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem

   OBJLOC = obj
   OBJS += $(OBJLOC)/testera.o
   OBJS += $(OBJLOC)/testerb.o

   LIBRARY_NAME = libtester.so

   libs:$(LIBRARY_NAME)

   $(LIBRARY_NAME): $(OBJS)
       ${CXX} -shared -o $@ $(OBJS)

   $(OBJLOC)/%.o: ./%.cpp
       mkdir -pv $(@D)
       $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

   tester_mn: LDFLAGS += -L. -ltester
   tester_mn: test.o $(OBJS) | libs
       ${CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
   ```

Comment: Edited the answer with complete working example. I don't think the "including concrete archive types" hint was required after all.

Comment: The documentation under "Reference/Serializable Concept/Pointer to Object of Thanks but Derived Classes" there is an example that looks to me they are serializing out a derived class and in a base class pointer. That suggests you do not have to serialize out an A* to serialize in an A*.  

When replace the EXPORT macros with explicit calls to register_type as in my problem description, I can serialize out a derived class and in a base class pointer without throwing an exception. My goal is to do the same with the macros.

Comment: I had a typo in my previous comment. It should start:
Thanks but the documentation under "Reference/Serializable Concept/Pointer to Object of Derived Classes" ...